# Promise with res.send();

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I'm using phantomjs with phridge for correct sharing pages for single page app. 
Here's some code example:

```
if (isbot(req.headers['user-agent'])){
    var url= req.protocol+'://'+req.get('host')+ req.originalUrl
    phridge.spawn()
      .then(function (phantom) {
         var page = phantom.createPage();
            return page.run(url, function (url, resolve, reject) {
                var page = this;
                page.open(url, function (status) { 
                    // handle page after load
                });
            })
            .then(function (contnt) {
                res.send(contnt);
            })
            .then(phridge.disposeAll());
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.error(err.stack);
            })

        }
else {
    next();
}
```

The question is - how the mechanic `res.send()` works with promise? Will be `phridge.disposeAll()` performed?

Comment: this line looks wrong - `.then(phridge.disposeAll());` does `phridge.disposeAll()` return a function? because the arguments to `.then` should be a function ... perhaps you wanted to do `.then(phridge.disposeAll);`

Comment: `phridge.disposeAll()` will be performed.
`res.send()` works exactly as in synchronous function

Answer (score 1):

You are making numerous mistakes. You should make sure you are familiar with `Promise` style programming before writing these code. See the last section.

---

In this case, no, because the

```
        .then(function (contnt) {
            res.send(contnt);
        })
```

part is not returning a `Promise`.

In this part, if you are sure `res.send` will not raise any exception, you could write:

```
        .then(function (contnt) {
            res.send(contnt);
            return new Promise()
        })
```

And the later part,

```
        .then(phridge.disposeAll())
```

Is also problematic, you should modify it to be

```
        .then(() => phridge.disposeAll())
```

even if it is the end of the chain and there is no use of create a new `Promise`, you should write it this way, because `then()` function takes functions, not result, to be its argument.

And you need to make sure each `.then()` branch returns a `Promise` like object while you are chaining them. (I did not check the others since I don't know what they returns.)

---

OK, there are more errors, I have seen redundant `;` after `then()` branch. I am not sure if there are more problems.

I think the problem is more serious: you are not understanding `Promise` style programming. You should read the ES6 Promise [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or Promise library (like [`bluebird`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html), depends on which library your library depends on) docs closely first.

Comment: Maby first read docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value

Comment: @ponury-kostek Yeah, I realized the author of the question could be unfamiliar with the topic, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would combine the `res.send` and `disposeAll()`. No need to over complicate the code.
`res.send` is synchronous and returns a boolean.

```
phridge.spawn()
  .then(function (phantom) {
     var page = phantom.createPage();
        return page.run(url, function (url, resolve, reject) {
            var page = this;
            page.open(url, function (status) { 
                // handle page after load
            });
        })
        .then(function (contnt) {
            res.send(contnt);
            phridge.disposeAll()
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err.stack);
        })
```